# Size of the Result object while querying huge data from HBASE table

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, mapr

I am trying to query hbase table with rowkeys. We have the following structure

- index table which has rowkeys of the actual table
- actual table which contains json data in compressed format.

When i am trying to query hbase, i have to scan first index table for rowkeys using scan with some filters which will results to byte array.(row keys).
Once we obtained rowkeys, we are invoking listofGets() in Table object. Once obtained we are iterating the object and prepare a list which contains compressed json objects.
Here we are not sure about the size and number of the objects. In case of number of objects is huge we may result in OOM. Do we have any options to return Iterator or buffering the results so that we can avoid OOM.

```
for (byte[] rowkey : indexTableOutput)
{
    Get get = new Get(rowkey).addFamily(Bytes.toBytes(columnFamilty)).setMaxVersions(MAX_VERSIONS);
    listOfget.add(get);
}
```

The above piece of code which is used to retrieve the keys from index table.

```
TableName tableName = TableName.valueOf("table1");
Table tableObj = conn.getTable(tableName);
Result[] results = tableObj.get(listOfget);
```

From the above piece of code we have few queries. Any help would be appreciated.

- If we have a huge number of data, Result[] will contain all the results?
- How to return a iterator kind of object so that we can leave it to consumer because keeping all the data and doing processing will result in OOM
- Any other options to return a limited data so that consumer do processing and continue

I could find a resultscanner is returning for scan objects. But couldn't find any other options for list of Get's. Here we know the exact keys from index table.

Comment: Maybe one way to think about this is to try the MultiRangeRowFilter? Not sure if that would be performant under your conditions, but if it works, you will benefit from the fact that you will be doing this via the Scan API, which gives you a lot of options for limiting the results per RPC call.

Comment: I think it won't work because i cannot predict the range from index table. suppose if i query for a specific data with some filter which will be distributed across the regions in that i cannot predict the rowkey range. Is there any Iterator kind to return so that consumer can manage the fetch. when i query the result which has 1 Million rowkeys will the result[] object contains the 1M objects?

Comment: I may have misunderstood your approach. I thought you first query the 'rowkey' table (which should give you a list of keys) and then from that you construct some sort of a multi-get call. So my suggestion was, since you have the list of keys from the first call, just create a list of row ranges for the MultiRangeRow filter and do the scan with it?